# Insert specific value on first $key in array

Tags: php

This is really grinding my gears:

```
if(isset($_POST['does_what'])){
    $strings = array();
    foreach($_POST['does_what'] as $key => $value){
        if($value[$key] == 0){
            $strings[0] = "This is $value";
        }
        $strings[] = $value;
    }
}
```

And this gives me error: `PHP Notice:  Uninitialized string offset: 0`

Im trying to insert "some extra" text on first key of an array. And the other keys should your be inserted.

Comment: The error generally occurs when you are accessing string or null variables with $value[$key] i.e. with array syntax

Comment: show `$_POST['does_what']` value by printing it out

Comment: Are you sure `$value[$key]` always exists? Maybe you need just checking `$value`?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`array_unshift`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_unshift.asp)

```
if(!empty($_POST['does_what']) && is_array($_POST['does_what'])){
    $strings = array();
    foreach($_POST['does_what'] as $key => $value){
        if($value[$key] == 0){
            $text = "This is ".$value
            $value = array_unshift($strings[$key], $text );
        }
        else{
            echo "Value is not a Zero";
        }
        $strings[] = $value;
    }
}
else{
    echo "Post is empty Or its not an array";
}
```

[`array_unshift` Example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_array_unshift)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something more like this:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    if (count( $strings) == 0)
        $strings[] = "This is $value";
    else
        $strings[] = $value;
```